# Isomorphism of rings between 2 non fields

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields, ring-isomorphism

Good day, I found a question which finds isomorphisms between 2 fields

[Find an explicit isomorphism of rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700259/find-an-explicit-isomorphism-of-rings)

I am, however, interested in finding out how to construct such an isomorphism if the domain and codomain weren't fields. Notably,

$\lambda:\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+x+3)\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+3x+2)$

In lectures, we were told a little about this and were hinted to use idempotents but I am not quite clear on how exactly I am supposed to use them. Can I apply a similar technique as in the question that I linked? Except I cant seem to make sense of how the author of the answer got the relations for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Do you know they are not fields. Can you write down explicit decompoitions of those rings?

Comment: I am not quite sure I follow. We have not covered decomposition of rings. I claim that they are not fields because the polynomials we are quotienting are irrecible in $\Bbb F_5$ and by Galois, that means they are not fields.

Comment: Well, each polynomial has two roots in $\Bbb F_5$. You can map the roots of one to the roots of the other by a transformation $x\mapsto ax+b$ for suitable $a$ and $b$, and this should give you an explicit isomorphism without messing with idempotents.

Comment: Alternatively you can factor the two quadratics, and then use the Chinese remainder theorem: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are coprime polynomials in $K[x]$, then $$K[x]/\langle f(x)g(x)\rangle\simeq K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\oplus K[x]/\langle g(x)\rangle.$$

Comment: @Lubin I am still not sure how I can map the roots accordingly 
$x^2+x+3=(x+4)(x+2)$ and $x^2+3x+2=(x+2)(x+1)$ over the field with 5 elements. To send, say, $x+2 \rightarrow x+2$, it is simply the map $x$, and to send $x+4 \rightarrow x+1$ I would need $x \rightarrow x+2$ or am I missing something? I am not quite sure how this gives me the isomorphism either since we have not covered this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found, is that using this rather universal method, such problems can be solved for fields and non-fields

Define a function $\lambda:\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+x+3)\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+3x+2)$
s.t.

$\lambda (x)=ax+b$

$\lambda(0)=0$

$\lambda(a)=a$

We can send the polynomial in the codomain to $\equiv0$ $mod(\text{polynomial in codmain})$ (notation is probably wrong but the idea will be clear below)

$\lambda(x^2+x+3)\equiv 0 \ mod(x^2+3x+2)$. Which means

$$(ax+b)^2+(ax+b)+3 = a^2(x^2+3x+2)$$

Should get something like $$2ab+a=3a^2 \text{ and } b^2+b+3=2a^2$$

Just plug in elements of $\Bbb F_5$ to see which ones solve the equations. I got, say, $a=3, b=4$

So, a possible isomorphism is $$\lambda(x)= 3x+4$$ **All that is left is to show injectivity, surjectivity and the fact that this is a homomorphism.**

It should all check out.