# Finding isomorphisms between quotient rings of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, factoring

How do I find an isomorphism between the rings $\mathbb{F}_5[x] / (x^2 + x + 3)$ and $\mathbb{F}_5[x] / (x^2 + 3x + 2)$? The rings have 25 elements each so any exhaustive approach seems unlikely. We received the hint of using idempotents, but I don't know how to even find the idempotents of each ring without attempting to square all 50 elements across both rings.

Comment: My guess is that you meant $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2 + x + 3)$ and $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2 + 3x + 2)$ instead.

Comment: yes, thanks. edited.

Comment: Yes, you did, but you wrote $\mathbb{F}[x]_5$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$.

Comment: i edited again after noticing that, sorry

Comment: Why do I get a strong vibe that we had question about exactly these two rings recently. Like last week or so?

Comment: Can you find it? Was there an answer? I've been stuck for almost 5 hours now on this, not a good feeling

Comment: Found! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675151/isomorphism-of-rings-between-2-non-fields?rq=1 . But there is no answer there either, so this isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : an isomorphism has to send a root of $x^2+x+3$ to a root of $x^3+3x+2$. The roots of your first polynomial are $1,3$, and those of your second are $3,4$.

Comment: Am I looking for a linear map which takes 1, 3 to 3, 4 in $\mathbb F_5$? If so, I can't find one. If not, I'm just totally confused

Comment: I've now found that $x \mapsto -2x$ works. How might I prove this to be an isomorphism?

Comment: @DG Since $\Bbb F_5$ is a field, $-2$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: OK, $-2 \times 2 = -4 = 1$. How does this help?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

- $x^2+x+3\equiv_5(x-1)(x-3)$
- $x^2+3x+2\equiv_5(x+2)(x+1)$

Comment: $x^2+3x+2=(x+2)\cdot (x+1)$. How do you get $(x-1)^2$?

Comment: @Levent My mistake! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this helps